# Why my variable becomes null at the end of all operations with the server?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, express, vite

For some reason after all operations with the server bookdata becomes null and no info shows up on the page. All queries work so it's probably a problem with frontend. I tried making bookdata update only once in multiple ways but i can't get it to work. I'm sitting at it for few hours already and I can't figure out what's the problem. If anyone can help me solve it thank you in advance.

**FRONTEND**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Book() {

  interface Book {
    id_ksiazki: number;
    tytul: string;
    autor: string;
    cena: Float32Array;
    wydawnictwo: string;
    data_premiery: string;
    liczba_stron: number;
  }

  const [bookdata,setBookdata] = useState<Book>();

  const location = useLocation();
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  const id = searchParams.get('id');


  const sendDataToBackend = async () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/book', {
      params: {
        id: id,
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      const data = response.data; // Otrzymane dane z backendu
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Błąd podczas zapytania GET:', error);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      sendDataToBackend();
    }
  
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/book', {
      params: {
        id: id,
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      const data = response.data; // Otrzymane dane
      if(!bookdata)
      {
      setBookdata(data);
      console.log(data);
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Błąd podczas zapytania GET:', error);
    });
  
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div id="book-page">
      <h1>Strona książki</h1>
      <h2>{bookdata?.tytul}</h2>
      <h3>{bookdata?.autor}</h3>
      <h4>{bookdata?.wydawnictwo}</h4>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**BACKEND**

```
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import mysql from 'mysql2'
//import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
//import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
//import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
//import dotenv from 'dotenv'

const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173', 
};

const app = express();
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(express.json());

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'shelfparrot'
}).promise()


app.get('/sprzedane', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const [row] = await pool.query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS sprzedane FROM zamowienia");
        const wynik = row[0]; 
        res.json(wynik); // Wysłanie wyniku jako JSON
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Błąd serwera" });
    }
});

app.get('/ksiazki', async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const [row] = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM ksiazki");
        res.json(row)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Błąd serwera" });
    }
})


app.get('/book', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const id = req.query.id;
        const zap = "SELECT * FROM ksiazki WHERE id_ksiazki = ?";
        const [row] = await pool.query(zap, id + 1);
        console.log(row);
        res.json(row);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Błąd serwera" });
    }
});
 
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```

**Console.log(data)** (2 times)

```
[{…}]
0: 
autor: "Karol Dickens"
cena: 50
data-premiery: "2022-05-31"
id_ksiazki: 1
liczba-stron: 600
tytul: "Opowieść o dwóch miastach"
wydawnictwo: "Wydawnictwo Zysk i S-ka"
[[Prototype]]: Object
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Comment: *"it's probably a problem with frontend"* - Can you do some debugging and confirm this?  In your browser's debugging tools, on the Network tab, when the AJAX request is made, what is the response body from the server?  In the browser's console, what did `console.log(data);` output?

Comment: 0
: 
autor
: 
"Karol Dickens"
cena
: 
50
data-premiery
: 
"2022-05-31"
id_ksiazki
: 
1
liczba-stron
: 
600
tytul
: 
"Opowieść o dwóch miastach"
wydawnictwo
: 
"Wydawnictwo Zysk i S-ka"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
length
: 
1
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
`console.log(data)` outputted two times

Comment: If that's what `data` contains in the AJAX callback within the `useEffect` then where/how are you observing that it's `null`?

Comment: `{bookdata?.tytul}`,`{bookdata?.autor}` and `{bookdata?.wydawnictwo}` are not rendering on the page.

Comment: Can you clarify (in the question, where it can be properly formatted) the *exact* data being returned from the server?  The `0` at the start of your comment, along with things like `length` and `Array(0)`, are somewhat confusing.  Are you receiving an *object* or an *array*?

Comment: Regarding the update... That *looks like* an array.  What happens if you use `setBookdata(data[0]);` instead?

Comment: It started working! Kinda stupid mistake on my part. Thank you for your help and time.